# input stream's purpose in operator >> overloading

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

```
istream & operator >>(istream & input, CustomLong & longi)
{
    string inputstring;

    input >> inputstring;

    vector<long> trans;

    for (int i = 0; i<inputstring.length(); ++i)
    {
        trans.push_back((long)(str.at(i)-'0'));

    }

    (longi.classVec) = trans; // assign vector to the class variable

    return input; //works fine without it

}
```

I noticed that the method works fine even if we don't return input, is there any problem that can arise if we don't return input? If it doesn't do anything, I'd prefer not to put it, because it uses unnecessary resources.

Comment: What "unnecessary resources" do you think are being used?

Comment: When you say "works fine without it", do you mean it compiles even though it's supposed to return `std::istream&` but doesn't have a return statement?

Comment: The sad fact is that it's undefined behaviour to not have a return statement when you need one.

Comment: it returns the number I inputed when I print the CustomLong object, which is strange.

Comment: also, does it return inputstream? I think I heard it returns something that helps the compiler link up with the variable next to the operator or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method itself may work fine, but if you are chaining inserters it won't.

```
std::cout << thisCustomLong << std::endl;
```

Will fail.

Edit:  Also returning a value does not "use extra resources" for any practical definition of the term.   Avoid micro-optimizing your program (I routinely work on systems than handle over ten million transactions a second (yes I got my decimal point right)) and I wouldn't worry about method like this returning a value.